# How to change the colour of a cardview when selected?clicked

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I'm trying out card view instead of a button, I love the amount of info you can add to them. But I'm trying to make it so if they press the card it changes colour. I want it to change back once they release, so that it works in a similar way to my buttons.

I can get it so that it changes on click but it stay like that until the activity is destroyed.

This is the code I use for changing the colour at the moment:

```
public void setSingleEvent(GridLayout maingrid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maingrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final CardView cardView = (CardView) maingrid.getChildAt(i);
        final int finalI = i;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Button: " + finalI, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mcontext.getResources().getColor(R.color.buttonPressed));
                if (finalI == 0) {
                    mcontext.startActivity(new Intent(mcontext, Genre_Streaming.class));
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `OnTouchListener` with `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` to handle Press/Release events instead of `OnClickListener`.

**Modified Code**:

```
public void setSingleEvent(GridLayout maingrid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maingrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final CardView cardView = (CardView) maingrid.getChildAt(i);
        final int finalI = i;

        cardView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
          public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Button: " + finalI, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mcontext.getResources().getColor(R.color.buttonPressed));
              if (finalI == 0) {
                  mcontext.startActivity(new Intent(mcontext, Genre_Streaming.class));
              }
            } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              /* Reset Color */
              cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mcontext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            return true;
          }
        }
}
```

**Link:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP

Comment: @markharropYou're Welcome! I'm glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an `onTouchListener` instead of an `onClickListener` to capture the "Motion event" this is an Object used to report movement (mouse, pen, finger, trackball) events.

```
cardview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // set color here
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // set other color here
        }
    }
};
```

here is a list of motion event constants from the android [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)